# Coffeescript 'click' issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm experimenting with Coffeescript but am finding it incredibly frustrating.

I had this script working earlier on today. I'm pretty sure nothing has changed.

The script is:

```
ready = ->
  class SortByLetter

    $('.letter').click ->
      selectedletter = $(this).text() 
      $('.location').hide()
      $("[id^="+selectedletter+"]").show()

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

The rails bit which this corresponds to is:

```
 <div class="alphabet">
    <%@findletter.each do |letter|%>
    <div class="letter"><a href="#" onclick="return false;"><%=letter%></a></div>

 <%end%>
 </div>
```

The output works fine when extracted and placed in a 'script' tag.

```
<script>

    $('.letter').click(function() {
      var selectedletter;
      selectedletter = $(this).text();
      $('.location').hide();
      return $("[id^=" + selectedletter + "]").show();
    });


</script>
```

EDIT: This is the full output from the coffee script

```
(function() {
  var AjaxLocationSearch, SortByLetter, ready;

  ready = function() {};

  SortByLetter = (function() {
    var showall;

    function SortByLetter() {}

    $('.letter').click(function() {
      var selectedletter;
      selectedletter = $(this).text();
      $('.location').hide();
      return $("[id^=" + selectedletter + "]").show();
    });

    showall = $('.showall');

    showall.click(function() {
      return $('.location').show();
    });

    return SortByLetter;

  })();
```

If anyone can explain to me what i've done wrong that would be great!

Comment: Errors in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)? Does it work again if you remove whatever you added?

Comment: Your CoffeeScript doesn't make any sense. You're creating a class but not instantiating it, you're throwing code inside a class and expecting something useful to happen, and that is not the complete JavaScript output from that CoffeeScript. I'm guessing that adding `class SortByLetter` was one of the recent changes you made.

Comment: @Juhana No, no errors in the console. Indeed, when the letters are clicked there's no call going out. Sorry, I should have said that i've removed the code I later inserted. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @muistooshort I thought I was instantiating the class by running it on page load using the 'ready'? The class was there when it worked - when i remove it there is still no change. I will edit to show the complete coffeescript output. That is just the output I added as inline JS to check it wasn't the syntax. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious from your compiled output that you have some indentation problems not reflected by your supplied CoffeeScript source code. Despite your class appearing to be indented within the `ready` function, your `ready` function is empty:

```
ready = function() {};
```

The stuff inside the definition of `class SortByLetter` is executing immediately, **outside** the `$(document).ready` callback, before the DOM is ready. This is the source of your problems.

Speaking of your `class SortByLetter`... What is it doing there? There is no reason for you to create a class if you're just trying to invoke a single function. Your `ready` handler should be:

```
$ ->
  $('.letter').click ->
    selectedletter = $(this).text() 
    $('.location').hide()
    $("[id^="+selectedletter+"]").show()
```

As it stands, you're creating a class, and then doing *nothing* with it.